# Django-filer get absolute URL and Django Celery Upload

Tags: python, django, django-celery, django-filer

Is it possible to get the absolute URL of a file just uploaded with Django Filer?

My problem is this:

I'm using Django Filer to upload music. I then want to submit this file to Django Celery to upload to Mixcloud using their API. But..

I can't figure out how to get URL of the file. I'm not using views, I want to just use the admin, grab the file just uploaded and send to Celery to upload to Mixcloud using their API. But i can only import the object from the model to celery.

My Model:

```
class MixcloudUpload(models.Model):
    files = FilerFileField(null=True, blank=True)
    data = {'name': 'API Test'}


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MixcloudUpload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        from .tasks import uploadtask
        uploadtask.delay(self.id)
```

My Task:

```
@celery_app.task()
def uploadtask(request):
    sleep(5)
    # Update the state. The meta data is available in task.info dicttionary
    # The meta data is useful to store relevant information to the task
    # Here we are storing the upload progress in the meta.
    post_url = 'https://api.mixcloud.com/upload/?access_token=ugY'
    from .models import MixcloudUpload
    mp3 = MixcloudUpload.files
    data = MixcloudUpload.data
    files = ({'mp3': open(mp3)})
    headers = {'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'}
    r = requests.post(post_url, headers=headers, files=files, data=data, verify=True)
    return r, r.json(), request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Filer sets the `uploaded_at` (datetime field) model attribute on upload. You can filter on this to get new uploads to forward to Mixcloud.

As for getting the absolute url. The filer documentation is a bit tricky in this respect. But there are two attributes which you can use:

- `File.objects.all()[0].path`, is the path to the file on the filesystem.
- `File.objects.all()[0].url`, the url path after the domain, e.g.: `/media/filer_public/23/23/34565b67-e1de-41da-3132-1403c335fdd4/test_img.png/`. You need to prepend your domain yourself. So the full path would be something like: `"http"  + urlencode(site_obj.domain) + filer_obj.url`.

Comment: Is this the correct way? mp3 = MixcloudUpload.files.objects.all()[0].path When I try this I get object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: The example `File.objects.all()[0]` was just so you could try it out. I get it your model is named MixcloudUpload and probably contains a FilerFileField? You probably want to filter by `MixcloudUpload.objects.filter(filefield__uploaded_at__gt=last_celery)`, where `last_celery` is a datetime object and `filefield` is the name of the FilerFileField. For each of those objects you can get the path.

Comment: Thanks, I've just updated the post so you can see a bit more clearly what im trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. When I try that I get `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, QuerySet found` I used 'files' as the field and 'now' as the Datetime object im not sure if this is right

Comment: I've not worked with Celery. But it seems the `request` parameter in your `uploadtask` function is actually the id of a `MixcloudUpload` instance. To get the path to the file you would then do `MixcloudUpload.objects.get(id=request).files.path`. However renaming the `request` variable is a good idea if this is the case.